# Excel Find lowest cell and return title

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet I need help with please.

I8, M8, Q8 contain the numbers.  If I8 is the lowest, return "WILL", if M8 is the lowest, return "AC", if Q8 is the lowest, return US.

Thanks,
Mitch

Answer (score 1):

If it's just those 3 cells, and depending on how you want to deal with cases where some of the cells are equal (if that's possible), you want a formula something like:

```
=IF(I8<M8,IF(I8<Q8,"WILL","US"),IF(M8<Q8,"AC","US"))
```

or

```
=IF(MIN(I8,M8,Q8)=I8,"WILL",IF(MIN(I8,M8,Q8)=M8,"AC","US"))
```

Both should work for your specific example, but which one is more helpful will depend on your context.